# Whats the difference between ArraySystem.Object and System.Object in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I created an array on objects containing different type objects and checked the type of each element. Then Converted the Array in to a List and checked the types of each elements But results are different ?

```
object[] aobj = {"",4,2.5,7,new object()};
foreach (var element in aobj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type is Array"+element.GetType());
}


IList lsit = aobj as IList;

foreach (var element in lsit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type is in List " + element.GetType());
}
```

Output:

[image]

Why is there `ArraySystem.Object` and `System.Object` ? Whats the difference ?

Comment: "Whats the difference" The word "in" and a missing space from your first WriteLine statement?

Comment: _a simple typographical error_...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look carefully at your output code

```
Console.WriteLine("Type is Array"+element.GetType());
```

The type is not ArraySystem.String (etc.).  The word "Array" comes from your code.  You are missing a space after Array to make the output clean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code due to a space between `"Type is Array"` and the element type change it to

```
Console.WriteLine("Type is Array "+element.GetType());
```

and your output will be corrected

Thanks & Happy Programming